# CQWP - Get Current Web URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, content-query-web-part, xslt

I am customizing the ItemStyle.xsl in SPD2010 for a CQWP crawling a whole site collection.
I need to use the current web as a variable.

I tried multiple options:

- Option #1 - use server variables in a similar way to what you do with a DVWP
  but I do not see where I would set up the  block

Ref. http://sympmarc.com/2007/10/19/data-view-web-part-parameters-based-on-server-variables/

- Option #2 - use the ddwrt namespace functions
  I have successfully added the namespace to the ItemStyle.xsl
  and it does work great to retreive the page URL

  xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"

Ref. http://spyralout.com/2009/03/16/current-page-url-using-xsl-for-content-query-web-part/

However, when trying the same trick to retrieve Httphost, HttpVDir and other parameters,
it simply didn't work (returned blank).
Note: my SP website is using https...

- Option #3 - Use the parameter(s) defined in the ContentQueryMain.xsl
  It seems that I should be able to access the paramters defined there from the ItemStyle.xsl but I probably don't do it properly...
  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this kind of thing often, you could create a new class that inherits from CQWP, and passes data you need through to the XSL, using the ModifyXslArgumentList method.

Ref: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/extending-content-query-web-part-with-custom-data/

Comment: I unfortunately don t have the ability/ or knowledge to go beyond SharePoint Designer...

Answer (score 0):

In `ContentQueryMain.xsl` are declared the following parameters:

- `SiteUrl` - URL of the current site collection
- `WebUrl` - URL of current web site

In `ItemStyle.xsl` *current web site url* could be specified as demonstrated below:

```
<a href="{$WebUrl}/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?id={$AuthorId}"><xsl:value-of select="@Author" /></a>
```

> Note: In order to encode URL string [`UrlEncode function`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa505323.aspx#officesharepointddwrt_urlencode) could be used